# update_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

My error:

[image]

Here is my models/user.py

[image]

Here is my serializers/user.py

[image]

here is my services/user.py

[image]

here is my views/user.py
[image]

Comment: Please do not add images in your questions. You can check how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

When this error occurs that means you have added an additional parameter to a function that should only take one.

remove the request.data in the `if request.method == "PUT"`
and try.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    user = user_update(id)
    return Response("whatever you want")
```

Comment: Can you check that as accepted